# Rhapsody TestConductor Experiences

Tags: unit-testing, uml, mda, model-based-testing

I was wondering whether anybody out there is actively using *Rhapsody TestConductor*? Or has tried it for a while, but then decided to turn it down for a particular reason?
If so, *what are your experiences*, in which field do you apply it, what are the shortcomings, or why did you turn it down?

At the moment we're considering TestConductor as our tool of choice for testing as it's already integrated into Rhapsody, and would like to find out how applicable it is to our project (btw, we're using Rhapsody 7.4 in C).

P.S: Recommendations on good books about Model Based Testing are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we are a mid-size company developing radar systems for airports, and we are using Rhapsody and TestConductor for quite a while. With Rhapsody & TestConductor, we have established an agile model driven development process, i.e., our developers (10 developers) are doing model driven design, and in parallel they are developing model driven unit tests in a seperate packages of their models. All that is integrated in a nightly build & test script, so every morning we get a status report about the percentage of passed tests.

We are very satisfied with it, since TestConductor is very well integrated into Rhapsody, and this really enables our iterative, agile development & test process.

BTW, I like the book "Model Driven Testing - Using the UML Testing Profile" from Springer